# A question on infinite series and boundedness of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ be a real sequence such that for every convergent real series $\sum x_n$ of positive terms , $\sum |a_n|x_n$ is also convergent , then is it true that $(a_n)$ is a bounded sequence ?

Comment: If $(a_n)$ is unbounded, you can choose a subsequence $(a_{n_k})_k$ with $|a_{n_k}|>k^2$ for each $k$. Consider the sequence $(x_m)$ with $x_{m}=1/k^2$ if $m=n_k$ and $x_m=1/ 2^m $ otherwise.